# Excel formula to generate series for 3 digit

Tags: excel

I am looking for generating alpha numeric series of 3 digits as below:
0A0 to 9Z9
i.e. 0A0, 0A1,... 0A9, 0B0.... 9Z9

Is there any way in excel to generate the above sequence?
I tried many formulas but not able to do with alpha numeric.

Answer (score 3):

You can try, in some cell:

```
=INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/260)&CHAR(MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/10),26)+65)&MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,10)
```

Then fill down to a total of 2600 rows

**EDIT:** If you want to repeat the sequence after 2600 rows, then try:

```
=MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/260),10)&CHAR(MOD(INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/10),26)+65)&MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy!

You're trying to `=CONCATENATE()` a series made of random integers and random strings.

- a RANDOM INTEGER from 0 to 9 --------------- `=RANDBETWEEN(0;9)`
- a RANDOM CHARACTER from A to Z --------- `=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65;90))` ¹
- a RANDOM INTEGER from 0 to 9 --------------- `=RANDBETWEEN(0;9)`

¹ See more at [ASCII Character Map](http://www.danshort.com/ASCIImap/)

---

**Final Formula:**

`=CONCATENATE(RANDBETWEEN(0;9);CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65;90));RANDBETWEEN(0;9))`

---

So, we used:

- [`=CONCATENATE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)
- [`=RANDBETWEEN()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4cc7f0d1-87dc-4eb7-987f-a469ab381685)
- [`=CHAR()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a)
- [`An ASCII Character Map`](http://www.danshort.com/ASCIImap/)

---

Or if you're not interested in random numbers and chars, should be easy to create a column with the necessary numbers to generate a specific sequence.

But.... if you want all combinations possible using these variables, or in numbers, all the 2500 combinations possible, you should create a macro. I mean... it's doable using formulas, but is way easier to accomplish this using vba.

Comment: I think, he wanted a sequence, not a random value.